# echo a function value won't pass on a form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, echo, payment-gateway

----UPDATE: trying to find a different solution [here, please take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27733000/2777324) -------
I am trying to post a form with hidden values on a shop platform with payment gateway to receive the values.
The value name "Order_Total" uses php echo called "$sum" to display the sum to pay like this:

```
<Input type="hidden" name="sum" value="<?php echo $order_total; ?>">
```

$sum is a function which reads the user order id amount

```
$order_total    = left_to_pay_for_order($oid);
```

the function works like this:

```
function left_to_pay_for_order($oid)
{


global $wpdb;
    $s = "select * from ".$wpdb->prefix."order_contents where orderid='$oid' and paid='0'";
    $r = $wpdb->get_results($s);
    $total = 0;
    if(count($r) > 0)
    {
        foreach ($r as $row)
        {
            $total += $row->price * $row->quant;    
            $shp = get_post_meta($row->pid, 'shipping', true)* $row->quant;
            $total += $shp;
        }

    }

return $total;
}
```

The Payment gateway receives all other values except the $order_total value.

**UPDATE !!! --------------------------------
The value passed as '0' - Any thoughts on that can happen ?**

I have tested and the function works prior to sending the form and redirect, **the sum display according to expected result on any HTML prior to sending, but the form send value "0".**

what am I doing wrong? have searched everywhere. your kind help is very much appreciated.

Thanks !!

As per request here is the whole Form page Code - modified per StackOverflow:

```
    <?php

    global $wp_query, $wpdb, $current_user;

    get_currentuserinfo();
    $uid = $current_user->ID;
    $user_email = $current_user->user_email;

    $business = get_option('Theme_tranzilla_ID');
    if(empty($business)) die('ERROR. Please input your tranzilla ID.');
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $oid = $_GET['oid'];    
    $order_total = Theme_left_to_pay_for_order($oid);
    $title_post = sprintf(__('Order Payment ID #: %s','Walleto'), $oid);


    //---------------------------------


    $tm             = current_time('timestamp',0);
    $cancel_url     = get_bloginfo("siteurl");
    $response_url   = get_bloginfo('siteurl').'/?w_action=tranzila_order_response';
    $ccnt_url       = Theme_my_account_link();
    $currency       = get_option('Theme_currency');

?>


<html>
<head><title>Processing Tranzilla Payment...</title></head>
<body onLoad="document.form_mb.submit();">
<center><h3><?php _e('Please wait, your order is being processed...', 'Theme'); ?></h3></center>

<FORM name="form_mb" Action='https://direct.tranzila.com/Terminal_Name/' method='POST'>
<Input type="hidden" name="supplier" value="<?php echo get_option('Theme_tranzilla_ID') ?>"> 
<Input type="hidden" name="sum" value="<?php echo $order_total; ?>"> 
<Input type="hidden" name="currency" value="1"> 
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $user_email; ?>">

</FORM>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you need to use ajax to get what you want

Comment: The PHP prints a value in the HTML properly? What does that line look like in the HTML?

Comment: Debug the function! Use `var_dump()` on all the variables in the function until you find what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks @JAL ! If I understand you corectly, the line is a dynamic numeric value which display properly in HTML. but is not passed on the form post.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen Thanks !! how do you suggest i do that properly ? (newby as one might see :) )

Comment: @user2777324 Read the [documentation](http://php.net/var_dump).

Comment: If the php properly produces a numeric value and it gets put in the input tag properly, that part is all set. The problem must be with the form html.

Comment: @user2777324 I think it's wordpress question too

Comment: @JAL What is the preferred way to fix the form html ?

Comment: Please post the whole form including the opening form tag to the closing form tag like you did for the sum input.  Is there any ajax involved in the submission or is it a normal form submission?  What is the payment gateway?

Comment: I see that the form is sending empty value for the "Sum" field. the function works well in HTML. I echo the username properly. what might cause the form to send "0" value insted of the function value ?

Comment: Assuming an actual value ends up in the html as you said it does and that you get the other input values on the other end, I can't see any reason for sum not to come through.  I tried looking for examples of that payment process code but all I could find is this http://www.bootply.com/phbBmYBpY4.  Perhaps that example could be of help to you.

Comment: Thanks @user2058037 but the code in the link is not what we see here.

Comment: What can cause a value not to pass ? any thoughts ?

Comment: I tried to copy paste your full page code you provided and got an error. 
Did you create a function called get_currentuserinfo()?

Comment: @Mai, it's a wordpress site. the function currentuserinfo is a wordpress function. there are also other values taken from wordpress theme functions.php. copy paste won't do the job here sadly :-(. what can cause the value to be '0' in the form instead of the real value ?

Comment: The form looks okay, assuming all of the php runs without errors.

Comment: If you remove the onload attribute in the body tag and view the page source what value do you get in the "sum" input tag?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles, the value read "0". where it should be something else obviously.

Comment: If you get "0" in the value attribute of the "sum" input tag then it appears the PHP function "Theme_left_to_pay_for_order", when passed the value of $oid, is returning "0". Double check that by adding "echo $order_total; exit;" immediately after the function is called. If you get "0" there, remove that and put "echo $oid; exit;" immediately before the function is called to see what value is getting passed to it.

Comment: you've left out something very important here....it seems to be running a js function called document.form_mb.submit() which i imagine (along with the absence of a submit button) is actually processing the form.

Comment: @David, the JS is sending the FORM properly. the problem is with <Input type="hidden" name="sum" value="<?php echo $order_total ?>"> that is sending the value "0" instead of the real value. How can I print the value prior to send into the form input field ?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles, how do I do that? where should I put "echo $order_total; exit;" and "echo $oid; exit;" in the code ? Thanks !!

Comment: After much investigation I have found that $oid is not passed on the form page. that results with the $order_total unable to provide results. $oid is necessary $order_total as it's the base of the function result. what might cause $oid not to pass on that page?

Comment: I don't see in the PHP you provided where $oid gets assigned a value. Did you leave that out of your example? Is there a "$oid = $_GET['oid'];" missing?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles you are correct, I left it out of the example. the actual code holds "$oid = $_GET['oid'];" - revised the example code. any thoughts?

Comment: In the page URL do you see "oid=" followed by some value? Something like: mysite.com/mypage.php?oid=4

Comment: yes! the page that I select a payment method - "tranzila" in this case - holds the URL as you wrote. clicking the payment method button leads to the above php file. I can fetch all data in the form except "$oid" and it's descent "$order_total".

Comment: Whats the full url? You can change the domain but your error seems to be within that step of the process. Also: do you use any security extension like suhosin?

Comment: full URL: mysite.com/my-account/pay-for-item/?oid=9, where order ID is the $oid. no security extensions are used, the page is directed to a secured page where all important details are then passed.

Comment: Can I create a temporary table prior to the redirect of tranzilla with "$sum" value, and send it inside the form designated field ?

Comment: In the function, can you echo the return value and check if it is 0?

Comment: @PeterStuart, In the form it return "0", where's on the previous page the echo is as expected "> 0". the problem is that on the form action - submit the order id ($oid) is not echoed, and order total($sum) is based on order id ($oid). can I echo the values into a temporary table and echo that into the form fields ?

Comment: Are you sure your `if(count($r)) {...` statement is being reached?

Comment: it is being reached anywhere on site except on the form. as if the action button is preventing the if(count($r)) {...

Answer (score 0):

Please, tell us what you see in a "inspect".. what the value in the input before post.

But.. with information that you give, I think:

```
1) You are missing a ; in the end of "echo $order_total" line. Put a ; in the end.
2) It can be some wordpress conflict with the "sum" field name. Try to change to "order_total".
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, have fixed the example code above. I can't change the input field name "sum" to a different one, the form is sent to another page where the "sum" field is expecting a value > 0. Do you know of a conflict as such in wordpress? Thanks !!

Comment: I don't know exactly, but, it's a possibility... I'm just trying something "out of the box" to help you. Can you check the $_POST there? The sum comes null, "" or it just don't go on post?