# Creating an Array of values from DB and passing into a Form

Tags: php, html, arrays, wordpress, forms

I want to create an array of Values taken from the DB and pass them into a Form.
I have a set of functions that calculate and fetch results:

```
$uid = $current_user->ID;
$user_email = $current_user->user_email;
$oid = $_GET['oid'];
$order_total = walleto_get_total_for_order($oid);
```

All functions have been tested and work well.

1. How do I create an array of the values?
2. How to take the values and paste them into a FORM and send ?

------- This is the a request for solution after tests on the question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730632/echo-a-function-value-wont-pass-on-a-form) - not resolved ----------

Comment: Why do you need to create a new question then?

Comment: Hi @Mike, the new question is a whole different question from the previous one. Previous question is about sending a form with values taken in the input field from different functions, where a problem is that the value for field "sum" is sent as "0" instead of the actual value. the above question is about fetching values into an ARRAY and afterwards creating a FORM with the ARRAY values and send. Am I wrong to do so ?

Comment: What do you want the form to look like after the array values are applied to it?

Answer (score 0):

Creating an array is quite simple :

```
$myarray = array() ; 

$myarray['uid'] = $current_user->ID;
$myarray['user_email'] = $current_user->user_email;
$myarray['oid'] = $_GET['oid'];
$myarray['order_total'] = walleto_get_total_for_order($oid);
```

Then you don't "paste" the values into a form, you set them as values and they will be sent when the user click on the submit button

Comment: What if the form submits on js onclick? can that cause some values to be different? as in "0" where the value should be "3".

Comment: It depends how you set your program, you can - or not -authorize the user to set different values. If you don't want him to modify these values, use hidden fields